# Can't run webpack in rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

I'm trying to run the rails application https://github.com/lumenlearning/OpenAssessments on a linux server. I've been able to get most aspects of it working, but I can't get webpack to run correctly. The [project readme](https://github.com/lumenlearning/OpenAssessments#webpack) states to run the following commands:

> $ npm install -g webpack
>
> $ cd client && webpack

Webpack installs correctly, but when I run it as stated, I just get the webpack usage help. I assume this is because there is no `webpack.config.js` file in the `client` directory. There is, however, one in `client/config`: https://github.com/lumenlearning/OpenAssessments/blob/master/client/config/webpack.config.js
If I run webpack in `client/config`, then webpack is able to find the config file, but I get the following error:

> Config did not export an object.

Should I be running webpack in a different way? I am very new to webpack.

Thanks!

Comment: The README says to run the following: `cd client && nodemon webpack.hot.js`... does that work?

Comment: It doesn't give me any errors when I run that, but connections to the server it starts are refused.

Comment: Weird, do you try just using Foreman?  `foreman start -f Procfile.dev` from the root?

Comment: I've tried that, but it runs the same `cd client && nodemon webpack.hot.js` and connections to the server are refused. At this point I also don't need the hotloading webpack dev server that it runs.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/towry/webpackrails-example

Comment: Checkout my gem for easy integration https://github.com/Darkside73/webpacked (I'm using it on several projects)